# Does we cache web service in java?

Tags: apache2

Currently we are using liferay web service. We want different implementations to cache the WebSphere requests.

What is the best approach to cache the web service in java with Apache Axis engine?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague: do you want to cache the *results* of the web service, or the *connection* to the service?

For the results caching, the obvious answer is a Map (HashMap), e.g., if your web service is used to look up some "Friend" object in your app:

Map resultsCache = new HashMap();

Alternately you could use URI objects instead of Strings.

A better approach is to wrap the Friend object in a CachableFriend that includes a ref to the Friend and also a timestamp, then run a background Thread to expire the Friend object (remove it from the Map) after some "reasonable" timeout period.